# Как отсортировать по времени и категории?

Tags: wordpress

генерирую посты с помощью аякса, категории у меня получилось вывести, а вот с датой проблема, дата в формате YYYYMMD, как сделать, чтобы отсортировать по выбранной дате, которая приходит, вот код

```
function pcht_posts($postID)
{
    $catID = intval($_POST['cat_name']);
    $timeProd = intval($_POST['time']);

    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'        => '6',
        'tax_query'             => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
                'terms'         => $catID,
            )
        ),
        'meta_key'       => 'get_date_sell',
        'meta_type'      => 'DATE',

    );

    $recent = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($recent->have_posts()) {
        while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __('No products found');
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в произвольном поле дата действительно хранится в виде текста `YYYYMMDD`, то должно работать простое добавление одной строки `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` в `$args`:

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'    => $catID,
        ],
    ],
    'meta_key'       => 'get_date_sell',
    'meta_type'      => 'DATE',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
];
```

Comment: Не сработало это, надо чтобы работало с тем значением, что приходит от выблора в табе, т.е через аякс

Comment: Интересно, как вы собрались сортировать по одной дате, вы вопрос сформулируйте уже нормально.

Comment: Я, возможно, не до конца донес мысль, есть табы с неделей, при выборе табов, делаю запрос с помощью аякс и отправляю дату в формате YYYYMMD , дата не одна как минимум их 5

Answer (score 0):

Делал буквально вчера

```
$args = array(
        'post_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'events',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'beginning_time',
                'value'   => array( date("Y-m-01"), date("Y-m-t") ),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            )
        )
    );
```

Думаю решение где-то рядом